# How can I use RSpec Expectations in PORO's

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-expectations

Hi,

I am trying to DRY up some of my specs. I extracted an Assertion class that does a couple of `should`s ... but most of the RSpec expectation magic is not working anymore.

I'll try to construct a simple example, to show my problem.

The object under test:

```ruby
class Foo
  def has_bar?; true; end
end
```

My assertion class:

```ruby
class MyAssertions
  def self.assert_everything_is_ok
    @foo = Foo.new
    @foo.has_bar?.should == true  # works!
    @foo.has_bar?.should be_true  # undefined local variable or method `be_true`
    @foo.should have_bar          # undefined local variable or method `have_bar`
  end
end
```

My spec:

```ruby
it "tests something" do
  @foo = Foo.new
  @foo.should have_bar                # works!
  MyAssertion.assert_everything_is_ok # does not work, because of errors above
end
```

Why can I not use the syntactic sugar of rspec expectations in my plain old ruby object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more trying I came up with this solution:

```
class MyAssertions
  include RSpec::Matchers

  def assert_everything_is_ok
    @foo = Foo.new
    @foo.has_bar?.should == true  # works!
    @foo.has_bar?.should be_true  # works now :)
    @foo.should have_bar          # works now :)
  end
end
```

The trick was to `include` the `RSpec::Matchers` module. And I had use *instance methods* instead of *class methods*.

Answer (score 2):

A more 'RSpec-like' way to do this is with a [custom matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/custom-matchers):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :act_like_a_good_foo do
  match do
    # subject is implicit in example
    subject.has_bar?.should == true
    subject.should be_true  # predicate matchers defined within RSpec::Matchers
    subject.should have_bar
  end
end

describe Foo do
  it { should act_like_a_good_foo }
end
```

Comment: That's nice. Thanks for pointing that out. It suits the simplified example I posted pretty well. However my real-world problem is more complicated and features page-objects and behavior-objects that need to access the Matchers (outside of the spec itself).